# Same Gradle files, same code base, different dependency graphs for different developers

Tags: gradle

This problem seems like a real mystery to me.  We are working on a Spring REST app.  On my team, we have Jenkins running a build on all checkins (CI build).  In addition, there is an official build done elsehwere nightly.  Some integration tests recently started failing during the CI build, and we traced the cause to jar conflicts.  However, we had successfully excluded the transitive dependencies that caused those conflicts earlier, and for the official build, and for some developers on the team, that is still true.  For others it no longer is.

We have the same code base, and the same Gradle files.  When I run the dependency task on my system, I have a long tree of transitive dependencies in one subproject (as does the Jenkins machine), whereas others have no such tree. In addition, the size of the WAR is several orders larger for some developers than for others.  The transitive dependencies come from another related project uploaded to Nexus.

I have refreshed dependencies both on my machine and the Jenkins machine, and even wiped out .gradle, but to no avail.

It sounds like something environmental, but the Gradle versions and Java versions are all roughly the same, a couple minor versions off at most.

Any ideas about what could cause this discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

You could force your dependencies to specific versions across the board

```
def gsonModule = 'com.google.code.gson:gson'
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        // add dependency substitution rules
        dependencySubstitution {
            substitute module(gsonModule) with module("$gsonModule:2.6.1")
        }
    }
}

// note: configurations block must be above the dependencies
// or build will error
dependencies {
    compile "$gsonModule:2.7"
}
```

Then when any developer/CI/test/CD runs the build your `resolutionStrategy` forces consistency across all compilations.  Default behavior in gradle is upon version conflict the newer version will be used.  This will force the all versions to the same regardless of their declared version.

```
$ ./gradlew dependencies --configuration compile -q

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

compile - Dependencies for source set 'main'.
\--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7 -> 2.6.1
```

Reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use gradle wrapper to ensure the same gradle version throughout, in order to exclude some possibility of that being a factor.

Also, add `--refresh-dependencies` to the gradle command-line.  It may be that some of your dependencies are not being versioned correctly, and this flag will verify each time that only the latest are pulled.

Finally, take a look at workstations that have different results, and ensure that you have identical [gradle.properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) in your gradle user home folder and the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks for the quick responses, but I have an update:

In short, one of my colleagues identified one of the problems.  I can't get into details, but the gradle files have convenience functions for either downloading another project from Nexus (such as the related project that I referred to above) or using a locally-built artifact if it exists.

Doing the latter resolves the issue.  Downloading from Nexus (as Jenkins did, and as you should be able to do) allows the issue to occur, exposing it.  I don't believe this effects the build order, but it does effect the transitive dependencies that are pulled in.

There are also some problems in the dependencies of the various sub-projects:  e.g., one project intended not to have dependencies has one, and that one is a big culprit in bringing transitive dependencies.  So when that base project is pulled in by other projects, it has ripple effects. And some of those dependency blocks need to be cleaned up.

Again, thanks for the responses!